# Javascript trying to remove items from a nested array and re-assigning to state without success

Tags: javascript, arrays

- `boxIds` => an array of unique file IDs received.
- Every `cluster` has an array of `files`.

I am looking to iterate over each cluster and look for a matching file id, if that id exists, remove that file from that specific cluster.

For some reason I am getting erroneous results while using `splice()`, since it's mutating the original array this creates a result that returns an array and removes every other file.

```
moveFilesToCluster: function(state,payload){                
    const boxIds = payload.boxIds;
    const moveToClusterId = payload.clusterId;

    let fileAddToCluster = [];
    state.assignmentClusters.forEach(cluster =>{
        cluster.files.slice().forEach((file,index) =>{
            if (_.includes(boxIds, file.id)){
                fileAddToCluster.push(file);
                cluster.files.splice(index,1)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I also tried (in this code) to add `slice()` before the `forEach()` (see above), but that isn't really delivering.

Comment: You've referred to "state." In many (but by no means all) systems with state, it's important that state not be modified directly. Is that the case with the state system you're using?

Comment: hey @T.J.Crowder, this is OK, `moveFilesToCluster()` is the mutator function that creates the deep clone.

Comment: I find it surprising that this is misbehaving given that you're cloning `cluster.files` and then looping through the clone but modifying the original. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: at the end, I would need to do a simple assign of `cluster.files = [new array with removed items]

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - fortunately I think this is more of a basic JS issue rather than a framework issue. the code is already there, just add items to arrays and run it.

Comment: Yes, I read the code, and it's not clear to me why it would misbehave. It is **your** job to make an example demonstrating the problem, not anyone else's. More [here](/help/mcve). You want to make it easy for people to spend their time helping you, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also tried (in this code) to add slice() before the forEach() (see above), but that isn't really delivering.

As I said in a comment, I find it surprising that that isn't working. Using `slice` as in your question clones `cluster.files` and then loops through the clone, and you're modifying the original. That should work. It's not how I'd recommend doing it, but it should work.

The classic way to do this would be with `filter`:

```
const boxIds = payload.boxIds;
const moveToClusterId = payload.clusterId;

let fileAddToCluster = [];
state.assignmentClusters.forEach(cluster =>{
    cluster.files = cluster.files.filter(file) {
        if (_.includes(boxIds, file.id)){
            fileAddToCluster.push(file);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

But if you want to modify the array in place, you could use a boring old `while` loop and only increment the index if you don't remove the entry:

```
const boxIds = payload.boxIds;
const moveToClusterId = payload.clusterId;

let fileAddToCluster = [];
state.assignmentClusters.forEach(cluster =>{
    let i = 0;
    while (i < cluster.files.length) {
        if (_.includes(boxIds, file.id)){
            fileAddToCluster.push(file);
            cluster.files.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: answer accepted, not only you've helped me out here, i've learned something out of it. Thanks.

Comment: @senseCode - Glad that helped! I'm still confused by why your version with `slice` didn't, but... :-) (It's not how I'd recommend doing it, but it should have *worked*.)